# How to create hexagonal imageview in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I am quite new to android, can anyone please tell me how to create hexagonal view like bellow in the image.

[image]

Comment: try using path class and porterduff

Answer (score 3):

[Shape Image View](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) can help you with your requirement

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.{ClassName}
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="8dp"
   android:src="@drawable/neo"
   app:siBorderWidth="8dp"
   app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"/>
```

[image]

in your case you can use `com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.HexagonImageView`

There are lot other shapes available, refer that library for more detail.

Have a look at [CustomShapeImageView](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView) also

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I rotate it like in the image

Comment: you can use `android:rotation` property of `ImageView`, as `HexagonImageView` also extends same class.

Comment: You r right , but when I rotate it using android : rotation it also rotates image

Comment: In that case you need to do customization with library.

Comment: can you help me in this?